# TFS : New Areas created not stored in the database

Tags: tfs

[image: New Area Created]

I have created a new area highlighted above.But this newly created Area in not showing up in the TreeNodes table (below screen shot) . Any idea why it is not showing up in that table.

[image: Database screen shot]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the newly created area not getting persisted? Are you not seeing it on Web Access, Team Explorer, etc.?

Comment: Actually i want handle this event , that is when an area is deleted . Please see the post here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693899/how-to-subscribe-for-nodedeletedevent-in-tfs

Comment: You can use TFS SOAP notifications. There is a NodesDeletedEvent that you can subscript to. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=330

Answer (score 0):

Check tables:

```
tbl_ClassificationNode
```

`tbl_ClassificationNodePath`